# Filter an array of object by object content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to filter an array of objects by its content, i.e.:

https://jsfiddle.net/z7g3unyu/2/

```
var arr =[
    {
    "uid": "1",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "uid": "2",
    "name": "Kate Roe"
  }
];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return e["uid"] == 1;
});

alert(newArr["name"]);
```

I wanted to create a new array that contains only one object which uid is equal to 1. However, it gives me undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two problems: your `.filter()` callback uses `=` instead of `==` (`=` is for assignment), and the `alert()` call should be `alert(newArr[0].name)` or `alert(newArr[0]["name"])` (either would work).

Comment: Although = was a misspelling, the second point is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you assign the value:

```
return e["uid"] = 1;
```

Use double equals `==` to check the value for equality:

```
return e["uid"] == 1;
```

Note that `filter()` returns **array**, not **object**. Use brackets notation `[0]` to get first element from an array.

See working snippet below

```js
var arr = [{
    "uid": "1",
    "name": "John Doe"
}, {
    "uid": "2",
    "name": "Kate Roe"
}];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return e["uid"] == 1;
});

alert(newArr[0]["name"]);
```

Comment: Also should note that `filter()` returns array , not object

Answer (score 1):

Using Lodash

```
_.filter(array, { uid: 1 });
```